# Install cypress on Replit project

Tags: cypress, replit

I am on a replit react typescript project. I have already installed cypress. However it is not possible loading shared dependencies:

```
node_modules/.bin/cypress open
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 13.6.6
Cypress failed to start.
This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
Please refer to the error below for more details.
/home/runner/Testing-with-Cypress/.cache/Cypress/13.6.6/Cypress/Cypress: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```
  { pkgs }: {   deps = [     pkgs.nodejs-16_x     pkgs.nodePackages.typescript-language-server     pkgs.yarn     pkgs.replitPackages.jest     pkgs.libgobject-2.0.so.0   ]; }
```

```
{
  "name": "react-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "testing with Cypress",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.0",
    "cypress": "^13.6.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "vite": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ytudev/ytusuite": "^0.1.7"
  }
}
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../lib/cli').init()
```

Anyone can tell me what's happening please? Thank you very much